# How insert files into database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to insert files into database in Android. example: insert 2-3 .txt files into the database.
Need the sample code to do this

Comment: Why would you insert files!? put them somewhere and store its name in the db. If you're still in need, check BLOB out (Im not sure if it will work)

Answer (score 0):

Android system uses an sqlite database - look here for a quick intro:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842

This forum thread looks to provide instructions on how to store files in a sqlite database:

http://forums.runrev.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=4674

Answer (score 0):

Sri,

There are plenty of examples on the web for using [`ContentProviders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and have it encapsulate the db implementation (good practice).

Here is a DIY example: [Write Your Own Content Provider](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/)